# Error establishing the connection between MATLAB and ROS

Tags: ros, ros-noetic, universal-robot, rosmatlab

I am trying to run the following code on MATLAB

```
deviceAddress = '172.28.9.67';
ROSFolder = '/opt/ros/noetic';
WorkSpaceFolder = '~/catkin_ws';
robotAddress = '127.0.0.1';

device = rosdevice(deviceAddress,'user','password')
```

I am getting this error which I cannot figure out how to get rid of:

```
Error using ros.codertarget.internal.ssh2client
Error connecting to SSH server at 172.28.9.67

Error in ros.codertarget.internal.RemoteLnxSystemExecutor (line 20)
            obj.Ssh = ros.codertarget.internal.ssh2client(deviceAddress,varargin{:});

Error in ros.codertarget.internal.createSystemExecutor (line 10)
    systemExecutor = ros.codertarget.internal.RemoteLnxSystemExecutor(deviceAddress,varargin{:});

Error in rosdevice (line 49)
            obj.SystemExecutor = createSystemExecutor(obj.DeviceAddress,...
```

I am running the LINUX shell on WSL platform, where the roscore is running and I have initialized the nodes in MATLAB as well. I also installed all the dependency packages for UR in the src file of the catkin_workspace.

Would be amazing if someone could help with this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the problem was I was mistaking my LINUX subsystem as my local host. Establishing a connection between LINUX(WSL) and Windows using SSH solved the issue.